# Is it permitted to lie if you love some one and want to get married to them?

Tags: nikah, lying

If a Muslim woman committed a sin with a man, and on confession to her boyfriend expects he would no longer want to marry her, is it permissible to lie to him and say it was all untrue? She would like to marry him.

Comment: As a general rule, try to frame any such questions from a third party perspective and try not to confess your sins to others that Allah SWT had already hidden from public view and kept it between Him and yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much but I want to know can I marry the guy who I told the truth too or can I lie and say I was just making it up would I be deceiving him ??

Comment: Im my experience one should never build anything based on a lie - it usually falls apart in the (near or far) future...

Comment: @sofiyah putting aside Islam for a minute (infact I don't see how this has to do with the academic study of islam), consider the types of relationships built upon lies. They are never sturdy. It's more of a social issue than religious.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you’d better notice that lying is considered as a haram act, then you should observe this matter. From the viewpoint of Islam, to save-facing (credit), we are not allow to express our committed sins, and solely ask Allah to forgive us (as @Ansari declared). Then you ought not to mention your bad past times. Of course it could be surveyed from another aspects such as:

According to Ayatullah Bahjat:

> In case that being virginity has not mentioned as a condition during
>   the Aqd (contract of the marriage) or the Aqd was not based on proving
>   of this matter, it won’t be the cause of option (termination of the
>   Aqd).

On the other hand, paying attention to the following issue could be beneficial for you that:

**Lying in contracts among marriage is not permissible, but telling the truth is not Wajib and …**

Consequently:

- firstly you ought not lie due to a love … (since in the mentioned
  issue, firstly you have committed a sin, secondly it will make some
  trouble in your future life that...)
- Secondly you’d better don’t mention the matter to him. Good luck.

---

**Reference**:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa9393)

Comment: "telling the truth is not Wajib" - i do not agree with that. it should be said if it is important. or if not telling has its own default meaning. so in that case not telling is lying and that is not allowed.